# Length of a delimited string with nulls ( not blanks ) in it

Tags: apex, string

I was trying to do some operations on a delimited string. I chanced upon a case where I got to check the length of a delimited string with nulls in it.

For Example :

```
String str = null+', '+null
```

Now `str.length()` gives me 10.

When I change str to `''+', '+''` , the length method returns 2.

I was just wondering, if null has no value in it, why does the string take it into account while calculating the length of it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `null` here ? variable or null
try to do trim() operation.

Comment: It's not a variable. Just a null.

Comment: this can be also used `str.replace('null','')`

Comment: This replaces all nulls in the string. But if there is an actual string called null in it, for ex: str = 'null'+', '+null ( one null is a string, other is just a null ), It replaces both of them which is not the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting ..

I tried this in dev console

```
string sone = null + ',' + null;
system.debug(sone);
system.debug(sone.length());
```

and the result is

```
23:21:38.057 (57852690)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|null,null
23:21:38.057 (57922386)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|9
```

and then tried this

```
string stwo = null;
system.debug(stwo);
system.debug(stwo.length());
```

result is

```
23:24:01.057 (57435220)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|null
23:24:01.057 (57698518)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

I m no Java expert but since Apex is based on Java, did some searching on null in java and found this discussion

[concatenating null strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java)

which says

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null"

**so your initial string concatenation of 2 nulls and comma and a space adds up to 10 in length.**

another useful discussion around null in java for additional reference.

[What is NULL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about `Operator Overloading` or `operator ad hoc polymorphism`.

So when you do `String str = null+', '+null` it result into a text:

> `null, null` // String concatenation takes place by `+` operator

Try this:

```
String nops = null+null // Arithmetic calculation takes pace by '+'
```

You will get an exception:

Also,

when you do `String str = ''+', '+''` it result into a text having two Characters `space` and `comma`:

> `,` // String concatenation takes place by `+` operator and there are two character.
>
> ```
> > Line: x, Column: y
> >     Arithmetic expressions must use numeric argument
> ```

So, the `+` operator behaves according to the data type you are joining with it. Technically it is operator overloading.

Comment: note that SFDC formula fields that use `&` operator against an sobject field value that is null will concatenate empty string, not 'null' (4 char string).

Answer (score 0):

The reason `String str = null+', '+null` has a length of 10 is that each `null` is taken as a literal text value (4 characters each) plus `', '` is an addition 2 characters for a total of 10 characters.

In the situation with `''+', '+''` only the `', '` is counted for a total of 2 characters.

With strings, the concept of null has little meaning. That's why strings should be checked using `isEmpty()` instead of tested for equality with `null`.