# Why does NULL count as 4 characters in Apex?

Tags: apex, string

If I execute the block of code in the Anonymous window, it returns 13 as the length of the string. Do null string count towards the string length in Apex?

```
String s = 'HELL YEAH';
String e = null;
String y = s + e; 
System.Debug(y.trim().length()); //Returns 13 characters. Should return 9
```

If I try something similar in a language like C#, the null does not count towards the string length. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BRZQt5) is the C# equivalent for this.

```
using System;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            String s = "HELL YEAH";
            String e =null;
            String y = s + e; 
            Console.WriteLine(y.Length); //Works correctly
        }
    }
```

Same thing in Java.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "HELL YEAH";
        String e = null;
        String y = s + e; 
        System.out.println(y.trim().length()); 

     }
}
```

Comment: Did you try your java example?  The output is 13.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Length of a delimited string with nulls ( not blanks ) in it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/86374/length-of-a-delimited-string-with-nulls-not-blanks-in-it)

Comment: This question would be easy to answer yourself if you simply debug the resulting string (`y`), which would show you `'HELL YEAHnull'`.

Comment: @PhilRymek I didn't realize it, till you pointed it out. The java code is a bad example.

Comment: I actually find C#'s behavior here unusual and unexpected. Maybe just because (almost?) every other language where you can convert a null to a string gives some variant of "null/(null)/None/undefined," but it seems odd to me to allow String + null and silently drop the null.

Comment: @Kevin [Not without problems the whole thing](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Apex Code, null actually doesn't count as any bytes (*per se*). However, when you add null to a string, it's typed coerced into a string four-characters long-- "null". This behavior seems to be rather specific to Apex Code. In other languages that allow null bytes in a string, null should actually be *one* byte long.

I was going to say something about UTF-8 not allowing null in a stream, but a brief search shows that I was incorrect. You can have null bytes in a string, but you have to do so by specifying the null byte. The only way I managed to get one of those is by decoding it from base-64 or by way of fromCharArray:

```
String s1 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('AA==').toString();
System.debug(s1.length());
// Outputs "1"
String s2 = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[] { 0 } );
System.debug(s2.length());
// Outputs "1"
```

I think the second one more accurately describes what a null in a string would look like.

Comment: In my specific case, the length of the field is causing an issue. I suspect I need to check for isBlank() in addition to the length of the field. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Isblank is indeed the preferable method; it checks for null, whitespace-only strings, and empty strings.

Comment: `'\U0000'` is a string containing only one null character, I think that's the same as the two examples you've given.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of converting a `null` string to the literal string "null" is consistent with `String.valueOf`.  `String.valueOf`'s behavior for `null` objects, including strings, is to return "null".  This is because `String.valueOf` calls `toString` on the passed object for its `Object` overload, which would throw a `NullPointerException` on a `null` object.  Rather than throwing, it probably has code that looks like:

```
public static string ValueOf(Object toConvert)
{
    if(toConvert == null)
    {
        return 'null';
    }
    else //Determine if toString is defined for the object and return accordingly
}
```